# How to list all the files which were not created on Thursday

Tags: shell-script, files

I need to delete old backups but I only want to keep Thursday Backups and delete the rest of the backups.

Give me some kungfu tips. I'm on RHEL if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think that last part is more appropriate on [martialarts.se], although it might be considered too broad

Comment: Can the dates of the files (mtime) be used as "Thursday Backups", or is there some date pattern in the filenames? If not, the creation date can probably be deducted from the timestamps of the files in the backup, but for that we would need to know how they were made (i.e. which program).

Comment: mmm.. you might get solutions if you said _modified_ instead of _created_!

Answer (score 5):

With GNU tools:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.backup' -type f -printf '%TA:%p\0' |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
  grep -v '^Thursday:' |
  cut -d: -f2- |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
  xargs -r0 rm -f
```

That looks for the last modification time of the files. If the backup was started on Thursday but wasn't finished until Friday morning, then the last modification time will be on Friday.

If the backup date is in the filename like `backup-2014-04-06.dump`, you'd do:

```
find . -name 'backup-*.dump' -type f -print0 |
  perl -MTime::Piece -0lne 'print if m{/backup-(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)\.dump$}
    && Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%Y-%m-%d")->day ne "Thu"' |
  xargs -r0 rm -f
```

Comment: When posting my question to the OP, I never even considered that the "Thursday Backups" might have "Thursday" in their filenames.... %-)

Comment: @Anthon They probably don't, but that doesn't stop us from printing the human-readable representation of the weekday of their timestamps (`-printf '%TA:%p'`).

Answer (score 1):

Set `ls -l` to show modification time week day (creation time in linux is ambiguous). Then just use awk to list all that were not modified on thursday (thursday=4):

```
ls -l --time-style=+%w | awk '$6!=4{print $0}'
```

Then you can parse this to get the list of files and iterate with a for loop or something.